# Using CodeMirror search function scrolling to show the string found

Tags: javascript, codemirror

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/na071dL4/13/) I have a `CodeMirror` editor that has three lines. I'm trying to implement the `search`/`searchcursor` addons by clicking on a button to find a string on the third line and position the highlighted result.

When the search button is clicked, the cursor should be positioned in the word `ccc` (the third line that is out of the editor view, so `CodeMirror` should scroll to that position and make the third line visible).

I'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'line' of undefined` even though I added the addons. Any ideas how to make this work?

```
<button type=button onclick="search()">Search</button>
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="cm" name="cm">aaa 
bbb 
ccc</textarea>


var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
    lineNumbers: true
});  

editor.setSize(null,30);

function search() {
  var text = 'ccc';
  var cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text, editor.getCursor());
  editor.setSelection(cursor.from(), cursor.to());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try loading corresponding search.js  file

https://codemirror.net/addon/search/search.js

https://codemirror.net/demo/search.html

Comment: look at the jsFiddle resources, I already loaded the search and searchcursor addons

Comment: try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq1p0bo/ )  you have to load dialog.js too

Comment: I need to search using my own input field and button. This code worked: `var cursor = cmEditor.getSearchCursor(keyword , CodeMirror.Pos(cmEditor.firstLine(), 0), {caseFold: true, multiline: true});
     if(cursor.find(false)){ //move to that position.
       cmEditor.setSelection(cursor.from(), cursor.to());
       cmEditor.scrollIntoView({from: cursor.from(), to: cursor.to()}, 20);
     }`